# Unlisted distribution of a Production verson of Android app

Tags: android, google-play, release

I'm looking for an equivalent of [Unlisted App Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution) but for Android apps. And I mean **distribution** of a production version. Previous questions similar to mine have closed or beta testing as suggestion, but I'm looking for a solution with

- Automatic updates
- Play Store page for an app reachable by a link
- No need to build a list of "testers" upfront

Basically it's like a normal app distribution, only the app can't be searched on Google Play Store. Client wants that for whatever reason.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic